# Vertical text direction in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, vertical

I have some Chinese labels to display on a map and I want them to be vertical, as the picture shows.

In another word, I want to rotate the label while keeping each character upright. How could I achieve this?

[image: example]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using QGIS 3.10 or later, set the orientation to vertical in the `Labels > Formatting`.

[image]

See also the [Visual changelog](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog310/index.html#feature-vertical-text-orientation).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

For younger than QGIS 3.10 versions, e.g. QGIS 3.4 open `'Layer Properties > Labels > Expression Dialog'`

[image: example1]

In `'Function Editor'` create a new function with such code:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def string_to_list(field, feature, parent):
    field_as_list = list(field)
    field_as_list_rot = []
    for i in field_as_list:
        field_as_list_rot.append(i + '\n')
    return field_as_list_rot
```

Apply `'Save and Load functions'`

[image: function]

And then slightly adjust the expression that has to be used as this one

```py
 regexp_replace(array_to_string(string_to_list("Name")),',','')
```

*where* `array_to_string()` and `regexp_replace()` are native QGIS functions

Click `'Apply'` and get the result

[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

Using QGIS 3.10 you can actually change the text direction under `labels > formatting` from `horizontal` to `vertical`.

[image]

Comment: What should do those who do not understand Deutsch? =)

Comment: Since the options are always ordered the same, I think the red box is sufficient guidance for everyone else.

Comment: lol ... that's an answer ... ach ...